# Сохранение состояния элемента

Tags: android, listview, sqlite

Вот, в чем суть: я практикуюсь в написании приложений для андроида и столкнулся со следующей проблемой. У меня есть `ListView`, по нажатию на любой элемент этого списка меняется бекграунд адаптера. Нужно, чтобы это изменение сохранялось после перезапуска приложения. Кое-где подсказали, что для этого надо сохранить изменения в базе, но как это сделать я не понимаю, хоть начальные знания по работе с `SQLite` имеются.
Не рассчитываю на готовый код, но был бы очень благодарен примеру.

Comment: хм, спасибо, я впервые слышу от такой штуке.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Бд слишком козырный вариант для такой задачи, надо использовать [SharedPreferences](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.html).

Comment: Цвет кодируется `long`'ом - например красный это `#FF0000`. Надо записать в `SharedPreferences` лонг и все

Comment: Я если честно не совсем понял как сохранить цвет для нажатого пункта. Уж простите.

Comment: Получается, что на место определения цвета:
((TextView) view).setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#757070")); 
я должен подставить переменную содержащую собственно цвет, и определенную ранее. А потом в onStop как-то сохранить, что у нажатого пункта бекграунд с определенным текстом. Как?

Comment: если у тебя их там всего 2, можно сохранять в БД boolean т.е. если тру - отображает один беэкграунд, если фолс - другой, если вариантом больше и есть возможность юзеру выбирать цвет самому( в чем я сомневаюсь) тогда хранить лонг, ну и если там всего пару пунктов - тогда просто хранить интовый номер пункта и по нему подставлять бэк. Вывод - почитай про SharedPreferences.

Comment: а вариантом тем(бэкграудов, цветов)?

Comment: 2 варианта цветов

Comment: http://developer.alexanderklimov.ru/android/preference.php   учи, матчасть, если что непонятно - пиши =)

Comment: Уже загуглил, прочитал и сделал. Но все равно спасибо))